# Report Viewer : Links redirecting to other reports do not work

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, report, reportviewer, error-reporting

I have some reports that optionally, redirect to another report.Of course parameters are passed during the redirection. The problem is that in Report Viewer the link that should take the action isn't clickable. This works fine when running from Report Manager.The links do what they're meant to (they link to other reports passing through parameters). When the report is run from the asp application with the report viewer, the links do not work at all.This problem became consistent when Report Viewer was upgraded from version 9 to 10 (to eliminate other problems).What should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not found what was the real problem.Sure it had to do with the fact that after upgrading Report Viewer from 9 to 10 while Visual Studio version is 2008 in our server.However it was resolved after copy-pasting a "good" cell, which did't cause problems from one report to the problematic ones.Only changing the link redirecting to the other level report was left to do in the copied cell.Now all it is fine.